# How do I use Visual Studio Code to connect to a newly created MongoDB collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, visual-studio-code

I saw this question was asked once before but the answer did not help my situation.

I am a beginner software development student trying to connect Visual Studio Code to a newly created collection in MongoDB and display the collection, through a python file.
I'm sorry if that explanation doesn't use established terminology, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing yet. I am using the code my professor provided and yet I get a whole host of syntax errors and a message that says **there is no module named `MongoClient`.** I am not allowed to use anything but VS Code so trying a different environment isn't an option. Here is my code:

```
Import MongoClient

from pymongo import MongoClient

url = “mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.zcfrz.mongodb.net/pytech?retryWrites=true”

client = MongoClient(url)

db = client.pytech

print(db.list_collection_names)
```

Any guidance would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing a "()" in my last line of code. I had print(db.list_collection_names), but what was needed was print(db.list_collection_names()). Since list_collection_names is a function I needed another set of parenthesis inside the print call.

Answer (score 1):

You Got this error saying there is no **MongoClient** simply because of the first line.
You can't import `MongoClient` directly you need to **import it from pymongo.**

you can read more about how to use `pymongo` on the official [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

So the correct way based on the code you provided is (just remove the first line):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.zcfrz.mongodb.net/pytech?retryWrites=true"

client = MongoClient(url)

db = client.pytech

print(db.list_collection_names)
```

**Also** you need to make sure you have `pymongo` installed. to do that read this on the python [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/).
I'm assuming you have `pytyhon3` and `pip3` installed . it's simple and straight forward just use pip to install it :

```
pip3 install pymongo
```

Alternatively :

```
python3 -m pip install pymongo
```

**Also** : i noticed you are mongodb+srv protocol so you need to install `dnspython` as well  :

```
pip install dnspython
```

Comment: What you say about needing to import MongoClient from pymongo makes sense,  but I removed the first line and got an error that reads cannot import name 'mongoclient' from 'pymongo'. I'm sure I have pymongo installed because a command prompt tells me "Requirement already satisfied" when I type in python3 -m pip install pymongo. I also keep getting syntax errors and the system tells me it's because of the ":" in the url variable's connection string, I remove it and it goes on to other random characters in the string. Any other ideas?

Comment: you didn't say which version of python you areusing, do you use any virtual environment ? there is a lot of things to consider.

Comment: are you getting error related to dnspython ? i noticed that you are using srv in the connection string i will update the answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 3.9.2, and to be completely honest I'm not completely sure if I'm using a virtual environment, I have set up a repository on GitHub, is that what that is? Also, I just tried to recreate the error to make note of the exact message but now it gives me something different that says "The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's surfix like `venv` or `conda` in your selected python interpreter located in lower left corner of VS Code. If not, you're not using any virtual environment but global one.

`pythonpath` is in Settings.json and could be generated automatically by selecting python interpreter. Run `pip show pymongo` in integrated Terminal to check if the module is located in current selected python environment. If it is, then you should import `pymongo` and use `MongoClient` without errors:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I simply don't know enough about this to follow your advice. In the bottom left corner of vscode I see Pyhon 3.9.2 64-bit. I don't know how to get to settings.json do I just type that into a python file? I'm not even sure what a python interpreter is to be honest. When I type pip show pymongo into a regular command prompt window (it won't work in vscode's integrated terminal) it shows the location as  c:\python\lib\site-packages. How can I tell if that location matches my "current selected python environment"?

Comment: Not sure if this helpes but now I'm getting an error that refers to my line client = Mongo_Client(url) and says the module is not callable.

Comment: @Andrew. Type `python --version` in vscode integrated Terminal, if the version is as the same as the selected one in bottom left corner. then the module you're going to install should be located in current environment.